# iOS return PageViewController instance from UIViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

In my app I have a `PageViewController` to manage more different layout.
Is there a way to allow to the instance of `PageViewController` from one of the content page(`UIViewController`)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just do

```
self.parentViewController
```

Or even explicitly cast it to

```
(UIPageViewController *)self.parentViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I've already tried but I can't cast it because when I call a method of the PageViewController I get an exception.

However I resolved passing the instance of the PageViewController when I call the content.